# How to insert dummy rows for distinct ids in a result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a result set as follows:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| ChildID | ReleaseID | Status | ParentSignature |
+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------+
|    1152 |        68 | Yes    |                 |
|    1152 |        70 | Yes    |                 |
|    5059 |        68 | Yes    | ad              |
|    5410 |        68 | Yes    | 111             |
|    5410 |        70 | Yes    | 111             |
|    5410 |        71 | Yes    |                 |
+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------+
```

In the above result set, there are 3 distinct values in ReleaseID column such as 68, 70 and 71.
Only one child id  (5410) has records corresponding to all the releaseids.

My requirement is to get an output result set in which there are records for each child for each release id with blank values for remaining columns.
The number of maximum distinct releaseids can vary. In this example, there are 3 releaseids.

Expected output:-

```
+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| ChildID | ReleaseID | Status | ParentSignature |
+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------+
|    1152 |        68 | Yes    |                 |
|    1152 |        70 | Yes    |                 |
|    1152 |        71 |        |                 |
|    5059 |        68 | Yes    | ad              |
|    5059 |        70 |        |                 |
|    5059 |        71 |        |                 |
|    5410 |        68 | Yes    | 111             |
|    5410 |        70 | Yes    | 111             |
|    5410 |        71 | Yes    |                 |
+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  1152  as clientid,        68 as releaseid , 'Yes' as status    ,  '' as ParentSignature    into #input       
union select   1152 ,        70 , 'Yes'    , ''            
union select   5059 ,        68 , 'Yes'    , 'ad '         
union select   5410 ,        68 , 'Yes'    , '111 '        
union select   5410 ,        70 , 'Yes'    , '111 '        
union select   5410 ,        71 , 'Yes'    , ''

WITH Clients
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ClientId
    FROM #Input
    )
    ,Releases
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT releaseid
    FROM #input
    )
    ,ClientReleases
AS (
    SELECT ClientId
        ,ReleaseId
    FROM Clients
    CROSS JOIN Releases
    )
SELECT *
FROM #input

UNION

SELECT ClientId
    ,ReleaseId
    ,''
    ,''
FROM ClientReleases cr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #input i
        WHERE i.clientid = cr.clientid
            AND i.releaseid = cr.releaseid
        )
```

Comment: ¬1 I took `SELECT INTO` from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can query as below:

```
;With cte as (
    SELECT distinct clientid, a.releaseid FROM #input x
    cross apply (select distinct releaseid from #input) a
) Select c.*, i.[Status], i.ParentSignature from cte c
    left join #input i
    on c.clientid = i.clientid
    and c.releaseid = i.releaseid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
into    #input
from (
    select   1152  as clientid,        68 as releaseid , 'Yes' as status    ,  '' as ParentSignature union all   
    select   1152 ,        70 , 'Yes'    , ''     union all       
    select   5059 ,        68 , 'Yes'    , 'ad '  union all       
    select   5410 ,        68 , 'Yes'    , '111 ' union all       
    select   5410 ,        70 , 'Yes'    , '111 ' union all       
    select   5410 ,        71 , 'Yes'    , ''     
) x 

SELECT * FROM #input x

SELECT  b.clientid
FROM    #input b
GROUP BY b.clientid
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.releaseid) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.releaseid) FROM #input a)
```

[image]

Note: If there is an `UNIQUE` index/constraint defined on `{clientid, releaseid}` then I would remove `DISTINCT` from  `COUNT(DISTINCT b.releaseid)`.